# Codename one Windows UWP Shop Build Fail

Tags: codenameone

When i try to make a windows UWP Build and send it to codename ones servers after 10 minutes the build fails and i do not now what is wrong so i was hoping that some here could get head and tail of the error file from codename one:

Error Code from Codename One: 
http://ge.tt/72DjT1c2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error was i have found out that in codename one preferences then under windows setting i had in build type Windows store build and it had to be Windows store upload